# Hide dynamic created div created using ngIf

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I'm trying to create this div on `ngOnInit` in angular

```
   ngOnInit(): void {

     let optTmp = '';
     for (let data of arrOption) {
       optTmp = optTmp + '<option>' + data.trim() + '</option>';
     }
     let sel = '<select name="select"><option value=""></option>' + optTmp + '</select>';
     let Word='<div style="position: relative;display: inline-block" *ngIf='+this.show+'">'+ word + '</div>'
}
```

HTML :

```
 <p [innerHTML]="Word">   </p>
```

Simply i want to render this created div on my `html` component. This `div` is being shown on my `.html` component but i want to hide it initially on condition using `ngIf`.

Any solution Thanks.

Comment: So, you're wanting to display a select with options populated from data, and then display what option was selected in the `Word` div?

Comment: @BrandonTaylor Exactly i want dropdown with div to be displayed on my html component based on some condition `*ngIf` i'm already using but this is not working

Comment: Have you worked through the "Tour of Heroes" tutorial on https://angular.io? If not, I would suggest starting there first.

Comment: This is what `*ngFor` is for. EDIT: Fully agree with Brandon. Angular has a tough learning curve, so it's essential to learn at least the basics before trying to write an app. The "Tour of Heroes" tut is excellent.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is to not use jQuery in Angular.

`*ngIf` isn't an HTML attribute, it doesn't stay in your template code after compilation, so you can't randomly add it the way you have here. Angular takes occurrences of `*ngIf` into account during compilation, and builds its own JavaScript logic to show/hide the element.

I can't repeat this enough: **don't use jQuery in Angular**. There may be a minuscule number of use cases where it's justified, but this certainly isn't one of them. There are Angular ways of accomplishing whatever you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Sorry, I can only upvote this one time.

Comment: @Will Alexander- Thanks for the answer i'm simply using `Word` variable using `<p [innerHTML]="Word">   </p>` without using any jquery will `ng-If` work on?

Comment: Why are you trying to bind to `innerHTML`? That is an Angular anti-pattern.

Comment: @user3653474 you're going to need to provide some more context to your use case in order for someone to provide an answer that applies

Comment: @BrandonTaylor I have added more details in my question can you please check